# Using ::target-text to put space between a label and radio element

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<div class="radio alpaca-control" name="package_plan" style="display: block;">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="package_plan" value="Boost Premium" checked="checked" class="">Boost Premium
        </label>
</div>
```

and i want to create space left of `Boost Premium` text with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::target-text

I have this

```
div.radio > label ::target-text{
    padding-left:40px !Important;
}
```

which doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. `::target-text` can only style [the following CSS properties](https://www.bram.us/2021/02/15/style-the-target-text-from-text-fragment-links-using-the-target-text-pseudo-element/):

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `text-decoration` and its associated properties
- `text-shadow`
- `stroke-color`, `fill-color`, and `stroke-width`